# Zgen zsh prompt broken

Tags: zsh, zshrc, oh-my-zsh

I was having issues with my zsh prompt when using zgen, first I had the zgen example code in `~/.zshrc`, it initially worked, and then I was moving the code around into `~/repos/dotfiles/.zshrc` and then doing `source ~/repos/dotfiles/.zshrc` in my `~/.zshrc`, but at some point my zsh prompt broke and I was left with:

```
devin%
```

without any colourz :(

I'm not sure what to do.

At some point it started working again after zgen re-generated the init script, but then stopped working again for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

By removing the init script, `rm ~/.zgen/init.zsh`, and opening a new terminal, zgen re-generated the init script, restoring the colored prompt. `zgen update` should also fix the issue, as it updates everything and removes the init script, which would be freshly generated next time you open a new terminal tab (if you're using the example `.zshrc` on the readme)